# Replacing text in lightning email template from apex

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage, lightning-email-template, replace

I have an Email template which looks like that :

**-----------------------**

```
Name : {ContactName}

Account : {AccountName}

{price} : {Cost}

Date: {MinDate}
```

**-------------**

I'm using the email template to send to a lot of contacts an Email using Apex (due to a lot of logic) and sometimes I even duplicate the email template with different data to the same contact.

In my Apex code, I'm searching the Word I want to replace with my data - after I do my logic.

Every line break [Enter] is replaced within the HTMLBody with `<div>&nbsp;</div>`

Now, if the contact doesn't have a {cost} to fill in, I want to replace {cost} and {price} with an empty string (''), and it work great so far - but the `<div>&nbsp;</div>` stays there, So what I get is an unnecessary line break in my Email :

body variable has the HTMLValue of my email template.

```
 body = body.replace('{price}:','');
  body = body.replace('{cost}','');
```

**-----------------------**

Name : {ContactName}

Account : {AccountName}

**Unnecessary line break**

Date: {MinDate}

**-------------**

I wonder, how can I delete the `<div>&nbsp;</div>` of the same row I just delete.

of course, replacing the `&nbsp;` doesn't give the desire solution - Its delete all line breaks in my template.

```
 body = body.replace('&nbsp;','');
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't replace line breaks (`\r\n`) with `<div>&nbsp;</div>`, because that's semantically invalid HTML. Instead, you should split the lines by line break, and wrap them in `<p>`:

```
Name : {ContactName}
Account : {AccountName}
{price} : {Cost}
Date: {MinDate}
```

Should become:

```
<p>Name : {ContactName}</p>
<p>Account : {AccountName}</p>
<p>{price} : {Cost}</p>
<p>Date: {MinDate}</p>
```

Of course, by your own reckoning, this still leaves us with `<p> : </p>`; you could replace that much more reliably:

```
body.replace('<p> : </p>','');
```

That said, I'd look into using Visualforce templates and the Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate method instead, which gives you the full power of rendering without manual parsing.

Comment: Right! THANK YOU!! that helped me a lot!